Why don’t Americans say “faucet water” instead of “tap water”?
For the place in the kitchen one gets water from, British English uses the word tap while Americans say faucet. Yet in a restaurant, an American does not say ❌ faucet water, but tap water.
Is this correct? If so, why?

Have a read of this (and maybe this). And yes "tap water" in the US.

Note, US uses "tap" plenty in other contexts, especially around beer, and perhaps carelessly for an outdoor "spigot." My perception is that, in earlier times, there might have been more distinction between the handle you turn and the spout the water comes out of, as these were often separate, while they're more often integrated today, with e.g. "the hot water tap" being the handle itself. (For that matter, early 20th cent. bathroom sinks often had two spouts as well.)

As usual, there's no good answer to "why?" questions like this. Things like this just happen.

Goole Ngram has nothing to plot for faucet water.

There's possibly a sane historical reason for this, now shrouded in the mists of time. The faucet saga.

Well, I say tap water but might say eithe water from the tap OR faucet, not never faucet water.

Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332690/tap-faucet-tap-water-faucet-water

In the US you might hear tap, faucet, spigot, or hydrant, depending on the region and the subcultural context.

@EdwinAshworth Aaarrrgghhhhh!

Wikipedia reports that "tap water" is also known as "running water, piped water, or municipal water." A U.S.-focused Ngram graph of "tap water" vs "faucet water" vs "unfiltered water" vs "plain water" vs "municipal water" vs "natural water" vs "undistilled water" vs "piped water" indicates that "tap water" is most common, but others have adherents as well.

@Robusto the question is "why don't Americans say faucet water?"  Since the most common word for the device from which the tap water comes is "faucet."  The assertion that Americans say "faucet water" was added by another user in an attempt at copy editing.  I have fixed that.

fragflan: The real problem with the premise of the question is that phrases such as "kitchen tap" are not particularly uncommon in US English. I am reminded of an English person who assumed that I must not know the word "trousers" because I am from the US. Trousers is a perfectly good US English word; it's just that we more commonly say "pants."

@ermanen I am not saying that you said "defines"; I said it.  If a word is used to describe something then a dictionary will have a definition defining it as such.  For example, you could say that "ant" describes a certain type of insect and also that your dictionary defines "ant" as a certain type of insect.

@phoog Thanks for the heads-up. I deleted my comment.


For the place in the kitchen one gets water from, British English uses the word tap while Americans say faucet.

Americans also say "tap."  A little searching on the web or in Google books shows that faucet and tap are synonyms.

Yet in a restaurant, an American does not say ❌ faucet water, but tap water.

See above.

Is this correct? If so, why?

Yes it is.  See above.

Faucet and tap are synonymous, and yet in the UK the former is very rarely used in speech–unless referring to American dialects–and in literature. The water from a tap is commonly called "tap water", so why isn't water from a faucet (a grammatical noun phrase) also called "faucet water"?  Interestingly, according to AmEng Ngrams,  the NP "water from the tap" appears much less poplar than "water from the faucet"

@Mari-LouA if faucet is very rarely used in the UK then I suspect there is asymmetry: tap is not so rare in the US.  It's entirely likely that this is regional (compare soda, pop, etc.).  I did a quick web search and found a number of US pages describing, for example, how water gets to the tap.  I also found several American results when searching for the phrase "kitchen tap."  When I searched for UK results containing "faucet," most seemed to be related to the sale of plumbing fixtures, especially from Amazon, which seems to confirm that it's due to US influence as you describe.

Because faucet is where the water comes from and restaurants don't typically serve water from a faucet, it tends to be from a dispenser. We do use the word tap to describe the water that comes out of the faucet.

What about the water that comes directly from a sink faucet? In American households do they say "faucet water"? If not, why?
